# How do I create a route to a raw text file

Tags: 8

I'm working on a Drupal 8 module, and I would like to include a couple of text files, each of simulated json data, as examples. How would I include these files in my module and create a route in the module.routing.yml file that would tell Drupal that when a visitor comes to mysite.com/examples/json1 to just print the text file (json data) as-is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a clever solution for this, but a simple straight forward solution would be to:

1. Make a Controller and use that in your routes.
2. In the method on the controller, load the contents of the file (or just hardcopy it into your controller method)
3. Return a JSON response in your controller.

I haven't gone into details on how to code this, there are plenty of code examples and documentation on this on drupal.org

Comment: I think the issue here is that JsonResponse is created via a PHP array/object and not the contents of the file. So in order to use JsonResponse, the contents of the file need to be encoded into JSON, decoded into PHP, and then passed into JsonResponse. I think that in this case returning a standard Response object with appropriate headers set would be sufficient.

Comment: In my case, the json file is small, so I just manually changed it to a PHP array. After recently learning about short array syntax in PHP 5.4, this is much faster.

Comment: @KevinNowaczyk If the files are not dynamically generated, this method is going to be an overkill, to generate static data. Creating a directory, and putting the files there is probably faster, if you don't need to make any elaboration on those files. I am not sure how making a wrapper for a JavaScript library makes any difference on returning a file content as it is, since you don't provide any detail about that.

Comment: So if my static json data is included in a module, wouldn't I have to put code in a hook somewhere to create this directory on installation and delete it when uninstalled? This sounds like it would be at least as much overhead as adding a route and a function in the controller. I'm new to Drupal, and even newer to Drupal 8,

Answer (score 0):

Create a route in your module.routing.yml and add the following route

```
route_name:
  path: 'examples/route_path'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\module_name\Controller\JsonController::renderJSON'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Then create Controller with the name JsonController and inside that create a function renderJSON like the following

```
 /**
   * RenderJson.
   *
   * @return json string
   *   
   */
    public function renderJSON() {
       // read your json content here.
       //encode your json using JsonEncoder class and return it 

    }
```